# Passing non constant argument to constant parameter

Tags: c++, function

Assuming I have a function like this

```
my_method(const vector<const T*> & param);
```

I wonder if I can call the function in this way

```
vector<T*> my_vector;
my_method(my_vector);
```

Comment: Unfortunately not.  `vector<const T*>` is not the same as `vector<T *>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a copy of the vector, but with const pointers:

```
vector<T*> pointers;

vector<const T*> const_pointers(pointers.begin(), pointers.end());

my_method(const_pointers);
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do what you are trying to do. `std::vector<T*>` is not the same type as `std::vector<const T*>` so the function argument does not match the function parameter.
What you are trying to do is not  "passing a non constant argument to a constant parameter", if it passing an argument of one type to a function expecting an argument of another type.
"Passing a non constant argument to a constant parameter" would be something like

```
my_method(const vector<T*> & param);

vector<T*> v; // non const vector

my_method(v); // OK, method takes v by const reference, so it cannot be modify v.
```

and that, you can do.

Note, in the example above `my_method` cannot modify `vector v`, but since `v` holds non-const pointers, the objects those point to *can* be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Try it out and see: http://codepad.org/dHQzwMyH

Short answer - no.  A

```
vector<const T*> my_vector;
```

will work, however.